# What is the length of an empty fixed sized array?

Tags: arrays, state-variable

Let's say we initialize a state variable as:

`uint[10] public fixed_array;`

This is a fixed sized array which is currently empty.

What would `fixed_array.length` return? 0 or 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that can be quickly and easily tested via [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.4.15+commit.bbb8e64f.js). If you haven't tried it you should give it a try

```
pragma solidity 0.4.15;


contract FixedLength {
    uint[10] public fixed_array;

    function getLength()
    public
    constant
    returns(uint)
    {
        return fixed_array.length;
    }
}
```

Running and deploying this contract results in `getLength()` returning `10`;

Comment: Looks like it returns the fixed size. Thanks for the answer!